# Azure Update Management for Windows VMs - Agent Not Configured

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, windows-update, automation

I am trying to manage Windows updates via Azure Update Management. I have successfully (or at least that is what the wizard told me) onboarded my VMs. From the Update Management section on the VMs you can see pending updates, however; under agent readiness it says "Not Configured".

[image: View of VM's Update Management section]

When I go to the Update Management section of the automation account I do not see any machines or missing updates. When I click Add Azure VMs I can see that all my VMs have already been added.

[image: Automation account's Update Management section]

[image: Add new VM to update management wizard]

It seems to me that I am stuck in some sort of limbo between being onboarded and not. I have tried reinstalling Microsoft Management Agent on the VMs and waited many days in case something just had not propagated.

Why is the agent readiness status "Not Configured" and how do I fix this?

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

-Chris

Answer (score 0):

The Scope Configuration was not properly configured and as a result the update solution was not being installed on the target machines.

The simplest solution was to just use the ["All available and future machines"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-onboard-solutions-from-automation-account#all-available-machines) option rather than try and fix the scope. This configuration was acceptable for my use case.

You can determine if this is the problem by going to the linked Log Analytics Workspace and running the following query:

```
Heartbeat

| summarize by Computer, Solutions
```

If you don't see `updates` under the solutions then something is off with the Scope Configuration.

For a lot more information and a far better explanation from Zachary Alexander see [this thread on MSDN.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a6b1c4f9-fba8-473f-a174-5379bd571dc6/problem-with-azure-update-management-agent-not-configured)